# Not able to run apply function in parallel processing using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply, pandarallel

I have data-frame which has colum named `label`. The values present in the column is :

```
label
[1,2]
[0,2,1]
```

I want to create a vector of dimension `240` having value `1` at positions present in label lits.

```
label_output
[0,1,1,0.......0]
[1,1,1,0,0,0....0]
```

I am trying to use `pandarallel`, as I have `60 million data points`

**Code**

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
import pandas as pd
import time
from pandarallel import pandarallel
import math
import numpy as np

pandarallel.initialize(use_memory_fs=False,nb_workers=10,progress_bar=True)

%%time
import ast
def cluster_vec(lists):
    
    b=[0]*240
    lists=ast.literal_eval(lists)
   
    for num in lists:
        b[int(num)]=1
        
    return b
    
data['clus_vec']=data.label.parallel_apply(lambda lists: cluster_vec(lists))
```

It get stuck at some point. Here is the screenshot of the processing.

[image]

It doesn't process from here.

Comment: Does it work when you run normal `apply`?

Comment: Yes, it takes 15 mins